# Getting array of classes from model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to get a prediction with the probabilities for each possible class.
The model is made with Azure autoML and I don't know what the index of the classes are.  I know I could get this information from multiple runs with different data that could predict different classes but I would like it returned each time.

```
def init():
    global model
    # This name is model.id of model that we want to deploy deserialize the model file back
    # into a sklearn model
    model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR'), 'model.pkl')
    path = os.path.normpath(model_path)
    path_split = path.split(os.sep)
    log_server.update_custom_dimensions({'model_name': path_split[1], 'model_version': path_split[2]})
    try:
        logger.info("Loading model from path.")
        model = joblib.load(model_path)
        logger.info("Loading successful.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging_utilities.log_traceback(e, logger)
        raise


@input_schema('data', PandasParameterType(input_sample))
@output_schema(NumpyParameterType(output_sample))
def run(data):
    try:
        resultclass = model.predict(data)
        resultprob = model.predict_proba(data)
        return json.dumps({"classes": model.classes_.tolist(), "probability": resultprob.tolist()})
    except Exception as e:
        result = str(e)
        return json.dumps({"error": result})
```

using

```
result = model.predict(data)
```

returns one of the classes like "PARTS"

using

```
result = model.predict_proba(data)
```

returns the array of the different classes probabilities like [[0.2001282610210249, 0.0636559071698174, 0.03661803212989511, 0.4096565578555216, 0.2866744587788889, 0.003266783044852147]]

following other recommendations I used

```
model.classes_.tolist()
```

which I thought would give me the list of classes but I get [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Is there a way to get all of the classes from the model?

Comment: Which model is this? I tried with `RandomForestClassifier` and returns class labels instead of indices.

Comment: Azure lists ```MaxAbsScaler, LogisticRegression```

Answer (score 0):

For a single prediction you may try `np.argmax` like:

```
proba = [[0.2001282610210249, 0.0636559071698174, 0.03661803212989511, 0.4096565578555216, 0.2866744587788889, 0.003266783044852147]]
np.argmax(proba)
```

If your got a 2D `proba` array from `predict_proba` try:

```
[np.argmax(p) for p in proba]
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but what I'm looking for is each class with the corresponding prediction like

parts: .23, 
sales: .34, 
admin: .03